EXCEL - Multiple rows = one data-point but how to get Pivot Table to know this
This is quite a weird issue to explain.
Essentially my data is in a "long" format. Multiple rows equate to one data-point. I've attached a photo of my power query to help you understand:
My worksheet is linked to a Microsoft form where new diagnoses, services, and ADFs can be written in. So i've made it so my columns will dynamically update adding new ones for new inputs (e.g. if someone wrote BPD and I didn't already have a column for this it would create a new one)
However - I have then unpivoted the columns because on my pivot table I need to be able to filter by diagnoses, services, ADFs, etc., and having a filter for EVERY single diagnoses would take up so much space. So I wanted to be able to filter diagnoses (and etc.,) all under one heading.
MY PROBLEM:
These unpivoted columns create a bunch of new rows for one point of data. For example, in the picture LEO now has 6 rows for their single response in month 9. I need my pivot-table that I then create to not put all 6 rows towards the calculations - as this is an issue when I come to sum some values, it majorly inflates the numbers.
I've heard of people using "distinct" or "unique" count for situations like these - but I am concerned as people with the same ID will appear multiple times regardless of my unpivoted columns as it is longitudinal, so LEO will respond again with a new data point in month 12 for example.
Hopefully this makes sense! - Happy to answer any clarifying questions!
Thank you for your help!
PICTURE:
https://imgur.com/a/juKh5Ir

Please upload your image to http://imgur.com and link to it, someone with enough reputation will likely embed it for you

I have now added a picture :)

can you concatenate/merge ID and Date then use unique on that combination?

It's still hard to tell what you've got, but given your description it seems to me you need to separate data into two queries: Respondents and Responses. Queries would be linked by Respondent ID. In Responses query, questions would be captured in columns and responses would be captured in a single row for a respondent. Making use of a foreign key relationship in the data model seems more appropriate than unpivoting the data and repeating repondent attributes for each response.
